# How to search all words which begin with std in an entire project but only display one occurrence of each result?

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to display all the different uses of the standard library in a C++ project I've just started to work on.  This way, I could study all the different standard library uses in the project and be well-prepared when I'll program.

I know this command can search what I look for :

```
grep -R "std::"
```

but my problem is that it returns 1000th times the same results : std::vector, std::array, etc...

I would like to only display once each occurrence the command finds.

Anyone knows how to pull this off ?

Thx!

Comment: what exactly do you want to display? the name of the lib (eg, `std::vector`)? the name of the first file in which a given lib is found? a unique list of all filenames containing standard libs? a unique list of filenames *and* standard libs? something else?  consider updaring the question with sample output from your `grep` command (eg, 10-20 lines) and then add the desired output

Comment: Collect all occurances and pipe the result into `sort -u`. Your `grep` outputs the whole line, not only the name of the entity. Note that by using the `-o` option of grep, you get the part of the line which corresponds to the pattern.

Comment: Tesla123: Did my suggested solution work out for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
grep -EowR 'std::\w+' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

- `-E` extended regex
- `-o` only print the matching part
- `-w` only matches that form whole words
- `-R` recursive

---

- `std::\w+` match on `std::` followed by 1 or more *word* characters

---

- `sort` sort the lines to get all duplicates collected together
- `uniq -c` count all the duplicates
- `sort -n` sort the result on the number of occurrences per match

Possible output:

```
...
    213 std::thread
    215 std::cerr
    231 std::getline
    254 std::move
    369 std::istream
    433 std::chrono
    524 std::cin
    602 std::endl
    629 std::ostream
   1277 std::vector
   1934 std::string
   4257 std::cout
```

Comment: Nice! I like the rich explanations.